# How to display date time as local time without the timezone at the end?

Tags: java, datetime, timezone, freemarker

EDIT: Due to some seeming confusion, let me clarify. If at all possible I want the solution to be done IN freemarker and not in java.

I have a datetime string that looks like this: `2019-03-12T16:02:00+02:00`
I have to show this in a specific format like this: `EEEE dd. MMMM yyyy HH:mm`
However, if I do it like this it shows the time as `14:02` instead of `16:02`. 
It converts the datetime to UTC and then displays it. How do I make it display the hours and minutes as is, just without "utc" at the end? Or any timezone for that matter.
`Tuesday 12. March 2019 16:02` is the desired output.

I do not know the timezone of the recipient.

Using `iso_local_nz` gives me the american standard display which is STILL wrong.

Thank you in advance.

I have tried just about all I can think of from here: https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_date.html#ref_builtin_date_iso.

```
departureScheduled?datetime.iso?string("EEEE dd. MMMM yyyy HH:mmz")?capitalize
```

The configuration I use is the following:

```
config = new Configuration(Configuration.VERSION_2_3_28);
config.setTemplateLoader(new S3TemplateLoader());
config.setDefaultEncoding("UTF-8");
config.setLocalizedLookup(false);
config.setLocale(Locale.forLanguageTag("NO"));
config.setTemplateExceptionHandler(TemplateExceptionHandler.RETHROW_HANDLER);
```

The string being fed in is the string I provided above.

Comment: you can use LocalDateTime from java 8

Comment: It displays the time zone as you have asked that with the `z` at the end of the pattern. As of displaying the time "as is", there's no such thing, since there is a time zone in the input string. But, if you set the time zone configurations setting of FreeMarker to GMT+02, you will get back the time as is. Would that work?

Comment: @ddekany Yes, that would work if all the dates in the template were to use the same timezone. 
If I wanted to show `12:00+03:00 - 16:00+02:00` "as is" then it would be printed as `12:00 - 16:00`. If I set a template timezone, then one of the times would be off by one hour.

Comment: @NoobsDeSroobs So in that case you wanted to show `12:00` and `16:00`? That's weird as then there's no single time zone where those are the proper local times. Anyway, if that's still what needed, then you have to remove the time zone from the string, as you did, so they in effect become local date-times.

Comment: @ddekany Yes, I have the times relate to different timezones and as such I have to show the time as per those timezones. Imagine a plane ticket. The departure and arrival timezones is reflected in the date and time shown for each respectively. Thanks.

Comment: @NoobsDeSroobs In that chase probably the cleanest solution is to have a `depratureTimeZone` and a `arrivalTimeZone` in the data-mode, together with the date-times with offset (not a local time). Then you can show the two time zone if you want (at least the arrival zone is probably interesting for the user), and then use `<#setting time_zone=xxxTimeZone>` before formatting the corresponding date-time. Anyway, maybe you have no influence on the data-model... just saying that an improper data-model is often the root of somewhat tricky use-cases on the template side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is by far not a good solution, but it works for the one case I have where the time I want to show is in the original string before it is parsed.

```
departureScheduled?keep_before("+")?datetime.iso?string("EEEE dd. MMMM yyyy HH:mm")?capitalize
```

Note the **`keep_before("+")`**.

The solution above works by removing whatever is after the `+` in `2019-03-12T16:02:00+02:00`. Then, the datetime parser assumes that the time is in UTC. Thus, I avoid the entire issue by instead using a built in string manipulation function that returns the substring that will not be modified further: `2019-03-12T16:02:00(+00:00)`. The bracket shows how it is interpreted.

If anybody has a better answer I will mark that as correct, but in a few days time, if no answer has been given, I will mark this as correct for anyone who might have the same problem.

Comment: Note that when you remove the time-zone offset from the string, and then parse it, it's interpreted in the default time zone (which is configurable in FreeMarker, but it's usually the system default time zone), not in UTC. And then when you format it, it's again rendered in the default time zone. So that's why it works.

Answer (score 0):

Use the class `java.time.OffsetDateTime` in order to handle the offset:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String t = "2019-03-12T16:02:00+02:00";
    OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse(t);
    System.out.println(odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("EEEE dd. MMMM yyyy HH:mm")));
}
```

This prints `Dienstag 12. März 2019 16:02`, translation depends on your system default `Locale`.

> Note that your desired output will not be produced by correct code, because 12th March 2019 was a Tuesday and not a Monday.

Comment: I think the OP is looking for a FreeMarker solution.

Comment: Not the answer I was looking for, but thank you for pointing out I had the wrong weekday.

Answer (score 0):

None of the answer above were good for a practical implementation so I did some experiments and this works perfect (in Java):

```
ZoneId userTimezone = ZoneId.of("Europe/Rome"); // To provide as parameter
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormatter
    .ofPattern("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm")
    .withZone(userTimezone);

String formattedDateTime = <any instance of ZonedDateTime>
            .format(formatter);
// OR
String formattedDateTime = <any instance of LocalDateTime> // JVM with UTC time
            .atZone(ZoneId.of("UTC")) // Adds timezone info <- Very important
            .format(formatter);       // Transforms the time at the desired zone
```

The string can now be used in any template/email that will be seen by the user of that time zone.

```
UTC Value: 20/03/2022 10:00
Output:    20/03/2022 11:00 // Without the timezone at the end
```