# How to convert date time string with zone offset to local time in freemarker?

Tags: java, datetime, templates, time, freemarker

I have a date time string in FreeMarker template with zone offset. The format of the string is "2019-04-21T08:23:27-07:00". How can I get the time "8:23 AM" from this string?.

```
Samples: 
Here is the output I am expecting from following inputs:
   Input                               Output            
1) "2019-04-21T08:23:27-07:00"         "8:23 AM"
2) "2019-01-17T11:23:27+03:00"         "11:23 AM"
3) "2019-04-21T21:48:27+00:00"         "9:48 PM"
4) "2019-03-18T15:48:27-05:30"         "3:48 PM"
```

Here are the things so far I have tried :

```
1) myTimeString?datetime?time?string.short.  -> Changes the time.
2) myTimeString?datetime.iso?time?string.short.  -> Changes the time.
3) myTimeString?datetime?iso_local?time?string.short.  -> Changes the time.
4) myTimeString?datetime?iso_utc?time?string.short.  -> Changes the time.
```

Java solutions are also fine.

Comment: try this:
  LocalDateTime dateTime = LocalDateTime.parse("2019-04-21T08:23:27");
  ZonedDateTime zonedDateTime = ZonedDateTime.parse("2015-05-05T10:15:30+01:00[Europe/Paris]");
  int h = dateTime.getHour();
  int m = dateTime.getMinute();
  int s = dateTime.getSecond();
  System.out.println("" +h +":" + m +":"+s);
  h = zonedDateTime.getHour();
  m = zonedDateTime.getMinute();
  s = zonedDateTime.getSecond();
  System.out.println("" +h +":" + m +":"+s +",Zone:" + zonedDateTime.getZone());

output: 8:23:27
10:15:30,Zone:Europe/Paris

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56985317/how-to-display-date-time-as-local-time-without-the-timezone-at-the-end?noredirect=1#comment100575190_56985317

Answer (score 0):

This can also be handled with the Freemarker-Java8 package: https://github.com/lazee/freemarker-java-8

```
${myzoneddatetime.format('HH:mm a')}
```